# How do I make a more asthetically pleasing page in Expression Blend

Tags: xaml, silverlight, expression-blend

I have created my first Expression Blend page.  It looks flat and dull.  WIthout going overboard, how do I add a touch of depth to this page.

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/looks%20like%20poo_zps3wt7phoj.png

I have changed it so that the LayoutRoot has a grey background and I have changed the textboxes like so:

```html
  <Border BorderBrush="#FF121111" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="90,194,192,0" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White">
     <TextBlock Height="33" Margin="6,6,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
        </Border>
```

But the textboxes still do not have the 3d depth that typical areas that ask for user input have.  For example, if you click to open a file in most programs, the area to add a file name looks as if it is more depressed (pushed down) so that the top of the box is defined and has a thicker line than the bottom of the text box.

I have a nother, simpler question that is related to this.  How do I do a test run of the page in Expression Blend to see how it performs and looks when I do a mouse over and mouse click on the controls?

Comment: I made a whole silverlight theme awhile back that used to be out on the microsoft expression gallery before they re-did their entire site and user experience and dropped the gallery. It's pretty cool, minified, and about 98% of the sdk controls style templates were re-written from scratch to cut out a bunch of the questionable stuff from the defaults. You're welcome to it if you like, just give me an address to send it to and I'll send it over when I get home. Might serve as a good starting point while you're learning how to customize controls.

Comment: wow.  awesome.  Gelsana.Xarzu@gmail.com

Comment: just sent it your way so you can del your email and avoid the spammers ;)